# List view indexing not properly worked

Tags: android, listview, sharedpreferences

I have three activities in my application. First activity shows the list of schools from web service in a list view. All schools are specified with special id. Then if any item is clicked then next activity opens and shows the list of students for that specific school in a list view. When clicked on any student the next activity opens and student attendance is noted down such as present absent and leave. If present is selected then green color showed, red color for absent and orange for leave

**Problem**

In the activity where all the students are showed in a list view, if I clicked on row 0 of the list view i.e Student 1 then attendance page opens and if mark present then I am saving the value in shared preference and in the student list activity I am getting that stored value from the custom adapter of the student and color the student row as Green. This all works fine but the problem is that as this is the 0 index of the list view and it shows green color. When I clicked on another school lets say School B then it shows the list of students for that school but the 0 index is highlighted as green too. Although I present the school A student 1 but it also shows green color in School B student 1. I know this is due to custom adapter because I am getting shared preference value in it but how to solve it? There is one custom adapter for students so how to change it? 
Main flow is this:

**School A - Shows the student list - Student 1 is present so first row of the list view becomes green. 
School B - Shows the student list - Student 1 is already green (because it gets the same shared pref value maybe for that index 0 ) although it is new school and students, I don't want this**

This is what I am doing in third activity when save button clicked then checkbox value is stored in shared pref.

```
save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("zero", MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
            editor.putBoolean("r2azero",one.isChecked());
            editor.putBoolean("r2bzero",two.isChecked());
            editor.putBoolean("r2czero",three.isChecked());
            editor.putString("zero", "zeroid");
            editor.apply();
```

and then in Student adapter I am doing this in getView:

```
boolean r2achecked,r2bchecked,r2cchecked;


Intent intent = ((Activity) mContext).getIntent();
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        SharedPreferences settings = mContext.getSharedPreferences("zero", mContext.MODE_PRIVATE);
        r2acheckede = settings.getBoolean("r2azero",false);
        r2bcheckede = settings.getBoolean("r2bzero",false);
        r2ccheckede = settings.getBoolean("r2czero",false);

        if (r2achecked == true&& p ==0)
        {
            v.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
        }
         if (r2bchecked == true&& p ==0)
        {
            v.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        }
        if (r2cchecked == true&& p ==0)
        {
            v.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
        }
```

where p is the position of the clicked item

Comment: If you can add the adapter/activity code for the 3rd list would be helpful.

Comment: Ok sir wait a bit

Comment: PLEASE check the updated code.

Comment: as far as I can see, you use the same preference name for all of the schools with key values of r2(a-b-c)zero. Why don't you use database structure, preferences shouldn't be used to store that kind of data. They should be used for simple configs, in some cases auth details. Could you please post the adapter and activity code?

Comment: @Inkognito is completely right. You can't use the same variable to manage all the possible fields. What you have to do is to create a class `Student` which manages their attendance and then save all the lists with students to preferences (although it's preferred to use a database, but the preferences will do just fine as a starting point).